# What technique can be used to simulate multiple clustered indices on a table?

Tags: sql, sybase

Are there any techniques which can be used to simulate multiple clustered indices on a table in Sybase 12.5 ? thanks

Comment: What do you expect from simulating them? What's wrong with `create clustered index`?

Comment: That's impossible.  A clustered index is the actual order of the data on the disk.  The data can't be on the disk in two different orders, so you can't ever have more than one clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think, you can simulate multiple clustered indices. Because when you have one clustered index created on a table, the data gets rearranged according to the data in the clustered index column. Logically you cannot arrange the data in another order in  a table according to another column. All that you can do is create non clustered index for other columns

Other thing you can do is combine two or more columns and create a clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

The only close approximation I can think of for this would be to create non-clustered indexes that include *all* columns from the table. In that way, the non-clustered index would contain all of the data.

However, to achieve that, the entire table would have to fit within any constraints imposed on non-clustered indexes. (E.g. for SQL Server, there's a limit on some column datatypes, and the whole size in bytes - probably similar restrictions apply in any product).

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create as many tables as you want and try different clustered indexes,which you want to simulate, on these tables. Then maybe run queries against these tables to check which one is performing better ,if your main motive is just to check which column would make a better clustered index. But i would advice that you should run full workload or all the queries which you will be executing against this table so that you will be in better position to see which combinations will be best for you.